# Validator Annotation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-validator

The custom error message is not getting displayed when I try to override the NotEmpty annotation error message.

Case: 1

```
  @NotEmpty(message="{username}")
     private String username;
```

message.properties:

```
 NotEmpty.username=test
```

Works fine.

Output in jsp page:

```
test
```

Case 2:

```
 @NotEmpty(message="{error.required.username}")
     private String username;
```

message.properties:

```
 NotEmpty.user.error.required.username=test
```

Where user is the pojo class.

Output in jsp page:

```
  {error.required.username}
```

Can I know what I made wrong in the above sample code.

Comment: you message.properties has `user.error.required.username` but your annotation only has `error.required.username`

Answer (score 0):

Please, check property name in annotation: in code you have `error.required.username` but in properties file you have a property named `user.error.required.username`. They are not equal. Hope this helps.